# showing error while starting ubuntu

Tags: dns, services, hostname

I have facing some errors while starting ubuntu desktop. I can't starting ubuntu. See below screenshot:

[image: erros in image]

How to start my OS. Anyone please fix this issus?

Comment: What does the last line say in full ?

Comment: `fsckd-cancel-msg: Press ctrl+C to Cancel all filesystem checks in progressfsckd-cancel-msg:Press ctrl+C cancel all filesystem checks in progress`

Comment: I tried with ctrl+C but cant work anything.

Comment: One or two failed services do generally not cause the boot process to fail. From the last error message, the system is simply checking filesystems for failures. You should let it do that.

Comment: it's automatically fixed but can't find the issues. @Jos